# Permanent location of an Image?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

I have a problem regarding my work.
What I want to happen is that I want to have my image a specific or permanent location. 
But every time I resize the window, the image also changes its place. And when I use .setResizable(false), I don't see the Text and the image.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ProgDraft extends JFrame {
private ImageIcon image1;
private JLabel label1;

ProgDraft() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ImageIcon pics = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("l.png"));

    JLabel logo = new JLabel(pics);
    panel.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
    panel.add(logo);


    JLabel title = new JLabel("Testing Title");
    panel.add(title);

    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    getContentPane().add(panel);
    getContentPane().add(logo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
}
```

here's the main

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;

    public class ProgDraftMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    ProgDraft gui = new ProgDraft();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    gui.setResizable(false);
    gui.setVisible(true);

    //gui.pack();
    gui.setSize(500 , 300);
    }
    }
```

thank you!

Comment: this will make problems, because it is the same: **getContentPane().add(panel);
    getContentPane().add(logo, BorderLayout.CENTER);** both components are added with BorderLayout.CENTER (CENTER is the default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already added the logo to the panel, yet you try and add the logo again to the content pane (Same with the title). The first add to the panel is negated, Which is bad because you need the FlowLayout to keep the position. Each component can only have one parent. Don't add the logo to the content pane. Just add the panel, and make the panel's layout `new FlowLayout(FlowLayut.LEADING)`. That will put the label to the very left of the panel. Then you can add an empty border for the label to add spacing to the label

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ProgDraftMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                ProgDraft gui = new ProgDraft();
                gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
                gui.setResizable(false);
                gui.setSize(500 , 300);
                gui.setVisible(true);           
            }
        });
    }
}

class ProgDraft extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon image1;
    private JLabel label1;

    ProgDraft() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));

        ImageIcon pics = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("stackoverflow.png"));

        JLabel logo = new JLabel(pics);
        logo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 0));
        panel.add(logo);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Testing Title", JLabel.CENTER);
        Font font = new Font("impact", Font.PLAIN, 30);
        title.setFont(font);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(title, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }
}
```

Learn to use the different layout managers. Don't try to depend on pixel perfect position. See [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

[image]

Also have a look at [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

Comment: cool! this is a big help! thanks and i will surely read the links you've shared. thank you again!